# How to do Ajax requests with error handling and detect overall completition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Some kinde of pseudo-synchronous question once again...

I'm looking for the best practice to run a function, after the completition of all ajax requests inside a loop.

Bad example:

```
var files = ["file1","file2","File3"];
var success = [];
var error = [];

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: files[i]
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("file found");
            success.push(files[i]);
            doThisWhenAllFilesChecked();
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("file not found");
            error.push(files[i]);
            doThisWhenAllFilesChecked();
        })
}
```

Bad example 2: synchronous, just to illustrate what i'm looking for:

```
var files = ["file1","file2","File3"];
var success = [];
var error = [];

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        async: false, // <-- !
        url: files[i]
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("file found");
            success.push(files[i]);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("file not found");
            error.push(files[i]);
        })
}
doThisWhenAllFilesChecked();
```

Comment: try jquery $.when(), it will call the success and error callback once all the ajax request are finished. Check the jquery documentation for more details

Comment: Thanks! "$.when()" looks promising, but could not figure out yet, how to use it in my case, since "fail()", "done()" or "then()" are no options to fire a function after the loop regardless of their succes or error handling.

I also found this answer, which i'm currently looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18425082/1536850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this-

```
 var files = ["file1","file2","File3"];
    var success = [];
    var error = [];
    var k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "HEAD",
            url: files[i]
            }).done(function(){
                console.log("file found");
                 k++;
                success.push(files[i]);
                doThisWhenAllFilesChecked();
            }).fail(function () {
                 k++;
                console.log("file not found");
                error.push(files[i]);
               doThisWhenAllFilesChecked();
            })
    }

    function doThisWhenAllFilesChecked(){
      if(k==files.length){
        k = 0;
        //execute code here
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good and easy! :-) I thought about using a "while"-loop in a similar way; i'm just not sure, if this is best practice...?!

Comment: i think using this code will not affect performance issues because its just using and if condition to check if the further code should be executed.

Comment: I marked this as the soulution, since it does what i've been looking for and is clean and easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain all the promises together, so something like:

```
var promiseArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //ajax returns a promise so capture this.
     promiseArray.push($.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: files[i]
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("file found");
            success.push(files[i]);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("file not found");
            error.push(files[i]);
        })
   );
}

//when can accept an array of deffered objects just call then() after these all return
$.when(promiseArray).done(doThisWhenAllFilesChecked());
```

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to
>   jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master"
>   Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds
>   it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as
>   soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as
>   soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected.

Note that `doThisWhenAllFilesChecked()` will run async also

Comment: I've been messing around with this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18425082/1536850), which looks like a similar approach, but the "then()"-event fires on each success and does not wait for all requests to be completed.

Comment: You may need to return a new promise, possibly from a always() inside your ajax call, it'll need a bit of playing around with to get everything to dovetail exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Note this just pseudo code

```
var files = ["file1","file2","File3"];
var success = [];
var error = [];
var promisese = [];
function xhrCall(fileName){
   return $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",        
        url: fileName
        });
}
function errorCallback(){
 // do something
}
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    promisese.push(xhrCall(files[i]));
}
$.when(promisese).then(doThisWhenAllFilesChecked, errorCallback);
```