# jQuery $.when, then, multiple AJAX requests, and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well after extensively web searches and several years of failing to understand documentation and finding alternative solutions, I've come to you to ask how I should go about my problem.

Note: Each AJAX request has a unique success function.

One of the suggested similar questions was -
 [How to loop through Ajax Requests inside a JQuery When - Then statment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424712/) - is this similar to what I need, albeit the incompatibility with my unique success callbacks?

```
$.when(

  $.ajax({
    url: '/-.json',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    complete: function(r) {

      //my stuff

    }
  }),

  $.ajax({
    url: '/-.json',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    complete: function(r) {

      //my stuff

    }
  })

).then(function() {

  console.log('leggo');

});
```

I based my solution on [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/) but console.log is never fired, though the AJAX requests are.

Thanks

Comment: If those are static json resources it's not likely they are set up to return `jsonp`. What does outer data structure look like? If they are remote api calls make sure that the api serves jsonp. Inspect actual requests in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: @charlietfl it's not the JSON -- previously I was making individual requests, etc.

Comment: So the individual requests worked using exact same `$.ajax` for each?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah :) and they still work and each success event runs correctly but jQuery is pretending there's no when/then

Comment: And same jQuery version? Add some error handling and see what that tells you

Comment: @charlietfl Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148355/discussion-between-thomas-chapman-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the `dataType`, as @charlietfl suggested. I have no heckin' idea why, but changing from jsonp to json was the answer. They're obviously more different than just the obvious situational usage.

Comment: `jsonp` is a very different type of request that requires a function returned and the request itslef is actually a script request, not an xmlHttpRequest (ajax)